# Execute callback function inside javascript object

Tags: javascript, callback, scope, javascript-objects

I want to execute a callback function inside an object. I don't know if there is something wrong in the way I'm doing this.

I've googled for a solution, also searched on stackoverflow but couldn't find anything similar to the way I'm coding this.

**PHPGateway.js**

```
var PHPGateway = {

    opt_friendlyURL: true,
    opt_folder: 'ajax/',

    callback_function: null,

    useFriendlyURL: function (bool) {
        this.opt_friendlyURL = bool;
    },

    setFolder: function (folder) {
        this.opt_folder = folder;
    },

    send: function (service, method, data, callback) {
        var url,
            json_data = {};
        if (this.opt_friendlyURL) {
            url = this.opt_folder + service + '/' + method;
        } else {
            url = this.opt_folder + 'gateway.php?c=' + service + '&m=' + method;
        }
        if (data != undefined) {
            json_data = JSON.stringify(data);
        }
        this.callback_function = (callback == undefined) ? null : callback;
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {data: json_data},
            success: this.ajax_success,
            error: this.ajax_error
        });
    },

    ajax_success: function (returned_object) {
        if (this.callback_function != null) {
            this.callback_function(returned_object.error, returned_object.data);
        }
    },

    ajax_error: function () {
        this.callback_function.call(false, {});
    }

};
```

Then inside the HTML file that loads PHPGateway.js, I've the following code:

```
<script>
    function submit_handler(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        form_submit();
    }
    function form_callback(error, data) {
        if(error == null) {
            alert(data.text);
        }
    }
    function form_submit() {
        var data = {
            status: $('#inStatus').val(),
            amount: $('#inAmount').val(),
            id: $('#inBudgetID'). val()
        }
        PHPGateway.send('budget', 'status', data, form_callback);
    }
    $('form').one('submit', submit_handler);
</script>
```

I get an error on `this.callback_function(returned_object.error, returned_object.data);`, the error is **Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'callback_function'**.

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is this the best way to do it?

Thank You!

Based on minitech answer, I've updated PHPGateway.js like this. I've omitted the parts that weren't updated.

```
var PHPGateway = {

    // Omitted code

    send: function (service, method, data, callback) {
        var url,
            json_data = {},
            that = this;
        if (this.opt_friendlyURL) {
            url = this.opt_folder + service + '/' + method;
        } else {
            url = this.opt_folder + 'gateway.php?c=' + service + '&m=' + method;
        }
        if (data != undefined) {
            json_data = JSON.stringify(data);
        }
        this.callback_function = (callback == undefined) ? null : callback;
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {data: json_data},
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                that.ajax_success(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                that.ajax_error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    },

    ajax_success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (this.callback_function != null) {
            this.callback_function(true, data.data);
        }
    },

    ajax_error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        this.callback_function.call(false, {});
    }

};
```

Now it works!!!

Comment: This seems to work fine for me. Is this code in the middle of some other code?

Comment: Yeah, this works fine. Your problem is somewhere else. As for "the best way" that's opinion based.

Comment: This should work fine. Are you maybe using a method of some other object as `myCallbackFunction`, and it throws a similar error when called, but not the same one? (Or maybe it is the same one and you’re actually doing some kind of recursive thing?)

Comment: This works, but is rather strange? You have a property that is null, and inside the function you overwrite that property with an external function that is not even called from within the object, you could just call the callback, `callback('Hello World!')` and it would be exactly the same ?

Comment: Wait, yeah, that’s actually pretty impossible (unless you have an unwritable property/sealed object/frozen object outside of strict mode, or a proxy). Please try to reduce it to a case that actually displays the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this generic example code with the intention to simplify the question, but on the real code I'm using $.ajax, I've updated the question with the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s your problem:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {data: json_data},
    success: this.ajax_success,
    error: this.ajax_error
});
```

When you set `success` and `error` to methods on `this`, they don’t keep their `this`. When a JavaScript function is called, it gets bound a `this`:

```
someFunction(); // this is undefined or the global object, depending on strict
someObject.someFunction(); // this is someObject
```

The built-in `.call`, `.apply`, and `.bind` of `Function` objects help you override this.

In your case, I think jQuery binds `this` to the Ajax object – a good reason to both not use jQuery and always use strict mode.

If you can guarantee or shim ES5 support, `bind` is an easy fix:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {data: json_data},
    success: this.ajax_success.bind(this),
    error: this.ajax_error.bind(this)
});
```

Which is equivalent to this if you can’t:

```
var that = this;

$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {data: json_data},
    success: function() {
        that.ajax_success.apply(that, arguments);
    },
    error: function() {
        that.ajax_error.apply(that, arguments);
    }
});
```

And now, a tip for you: don’t namespace, and if you do, don’t use `this`. `this` is great for objects that are meant to be constructed. What would seem more appropriate is something like this, if you really have to:

```
var PHPGateway = (function() {
    var callbackFunction;
    var options = {
        friendlyURL: true,
        …
    };
    …

    function send(service, method, data, callback) {
        …
    }
    …

    return { send: send };
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer this, you were very helpful.

Based on your response, I've updated the code and now works. The full code doesn't fit on this comment, I've updated my question to show the final code.

And thank you for the tip, I don't understand the line return {send:send}, what is that for?

Comment: @GonzaloMassa: The idea is that you don’t create the object that holds the things in your namespace until the very end, so all the functions are part of the scope for easy access instead of inside another object. But you still need to expose it, and that part exposes it in the same way you originally had everything.

Comment: So I should also add **useFriendlyURL** and **setFolder** on the return object? Both functions should be able to be called from outside.

Answer (score 2):

In your call to $.ajax, you need to add a `context` option:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {data: json_data},
    context: this,
    success: this.ajax_success,
    error: this.ajax_error
});
```

Your `this` variable in your Ajax success and error handlers are not pointing to the object you think they are. The `context` option to $.ajax() sets which object `this` points to in the Ajax callbacks.

Comment: Greg, thank you for your response. Your method is simpler, but minitech's answer helped me also to understand the __scope__ issue, even if I don't use jQuery. I wish I could mark both questions as accepted.

Comment: Heh, oops! Good answer.

Comment: @Gonzalo Massa: No problem. :) Glad I could help.